# Reduce changes in merge requests in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

Im using gitlab, and am trying to follow the gitflow process.

Whenever we have a new feature, we branch from `develop` branch.
Then merge back into this branch once the merge request has been approved.

But merge requests are getting more and more changes, if there is only a few commits.

[image]

And this makes it impossible to have discussions on the Changes/diff tab of the merge request.

How do I configure Gitlab so we dont get all these historical and redundant changes?

In this particular example there is only two commits - and one file changed.

Comment: What is your gitflow exactly? Using a proper flow, it shouldn't show large amount of changes (as this is both bad for the user reviewing, and for git itself with merge conflicts)

Comment: The number does not mean anything. It would be more useful if you address specific changes which you find unexpected.

Comment: As the number increases the more unusable gitlab becomes. And it serves no purpose to show so many irrelevant changes in a merge request with only 2 commits. So I am clearly doing something wrong - but am not sure what.

Comment: You wouldn't have to show all 125 of them, just a sample of "here's some changes Gitlab is showing that I don't think I made" would help. Although a [mcve] is always best, if you can construct one.

Answer (score 0):

This happens if you use few remote repositories and doing merges from one to another. I also couldn't find a solution except changing the flow and do not crossmerge via few remote repositories.